# Is it possible for Oracle to run the old version of a package even after you've done a CREATE or REPLACE?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, package

I have a package which I've just replaced and the method being called (ASP.NET client) is raising an error about an incorrect number of parameters.

If Oracle is still running the old version, how can I get it to discard the old "compiled" version?

Comment: You have just one database user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle 10g won't run the old version of a package after you've done a `CREATE OR REPLACE` (I'm assuming that you did that both for the package spec and the package body).

If you were using 11.2 and explicitly asked it do, Oracle can run two different versions of a piece of code in two different editions which would let some clients continue using the old edition and gradually migrate to the new edition.  [Edition-based redefinition](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/11g/EditionBasedRedefinition_11gR2.php) is new in 11.2 though.

Comment: @CadeRoux i've seen this a lot when you have a owner and non-owner users and the same package name compiled for both, but whit different signatures.

Comment: @SérgioMichels Looks like maybe just a DLL wasn't changed on a deployment - unfortunately I've got to move on to other things and can't dig into that right now.